# List view item to which scroll bar points at

Tags: android, listview, position, scrollbar

I want to know to which listview item my scrollbar is pointing to so that when I click on the scrollbar image, I can show a popup related to the listview item

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);

        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);;
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        text.setText("itemitemitemitemitemitemitemitemitemitemitemitemititemitemitemmitetemitemitemitemitemitememitemitemitemiitemitemitemitem "+position);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);
        return vi;
    }
```

Comment: can you please post some code ?

Comment: Shilpa, you want to show popup on scroll of the listview or on click on the list item? can you please clarify?

Comment: No. I have a customized scrollbar. I am displaying an image in place of the default scrollbar. So on click of that image, i want to open a popup related to the list item that is adjacent to the scrollbar image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement onScroll method of listview like below:

```
YOURLISTVIEW.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                  //Inside this method you can calculate and can found current position
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                  //Inside this method you can calculate and can found current position, here you have firstVisibleitem and total visible item count, so I think using it, you can calculate current position.

        }
    });
```

Comment: But i need the position of the item adjacent to the scrollbar

Comment: Ya so you have to calculate as per your need, you have first item and total item so you can calculate current position.

Answer (score 0):

I think will be better if you use `OnItemClickListener`. When you click on some position you will know exactly which position has that item.